# Swift Array of Types element not recognised as type

Tags: ios, swift, gamekit

I have the following implementation of some GKStates

```swift
import GameplayKit.GKState

class Running: GKState {
    let validNextStates: [GKState.Type] = [Paused.self, Over.self]
    
    override func isValidNextState(_ stateClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
        return self.validNextStates.contains(where: { stateClass is $0 })
    }
}

class Paused: GKState {}

class Over: GKState {}
```

Does anyone have a hint on why I get `Expected type after 'is'` at `$0`? `validNextStates` is defined as an array of GKState Types so why is one of it's elements not recognised as a Type?

Edit:

Xcode: Version 12.1 (12A7403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the type of `stateClass`. `stateClass` is of type `AnyClass`, which is just a typealias for `AnyObject.Type` and hence `stateClass` is a meta-type, not a normal type, so the `is` operator cannot be used on it.

However, to compare meta types, you can use the equality operator.

```
class Running: GKState {
    let validNextStates: [GKState.Type] = [Paused.self, Over.self]

    override func isValidNextState(_ stateClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
        return self.validNextStates.contains(where: { $0 == stateClass })
    }
}

class Paused: GKState {}
class Over: GKState {}
class Invalid: GKState {}

Running().isValidNextState(Paused.self) // true
Running().isValidNextState(Invalid.self) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

`is` can't be used on variables.

It could have been a valid choice if GameplayKit weren't written in Objective-C. Unfortunately, there's no way to forward this to `isValidNextState`, because `AnyClass` isn't enough information, so use `==` like Dávid showed.

```swift
func validateNextState<State: GKState>(_: State.Type) throws {
  guard ( validNextStates.contains { $0 is State.Type } )
  else { throw GKState.Error.invalid }
}
```

```swift
extension GKState {
  enum Error: Swift.Error {
    case invalid
  }
}
```